# I cant change sa password in mssql 2005 "Could not find stored procedure 'master.dbo.sp_password'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider"

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

We have an old ms sql 2005 server and for some reason, most of  the features in sa account settings are grayed out.. 
[image]

Even I cant change sa password It will though this error "Could not find stored procedure 'master.dbo.sp_password'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider"

[image]

Though I have enabled mixed mode I cant login using sa account.. (only windows authentication works)

[image]

Any help where to start troubleshooting steps? googled around a day and yet could not find a clue fixing the issue.. Thanks in advanced for any tip!

PS:only the default instance is having this issue.. other one is fine, login working for sa and not grayed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with your master database.
Several of your system stored procedures appear to be missing (judging by the look of the ssms prompt)

You may want to [Restore your master database from backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190679.aspx).

1. [Start the server instance in single-user mode.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345416.aspx)
2. RESTORE DATABASE master FROM  WITH REPLACE

Just make sure you backup everything before you do this.
Clearly something is broken on your environment, so make sure that no matter what happens, your data is safe.

Comment: So i have to search for full backup of server ? i have two instance, only the default instance is having this issue.. other one is fine, login working for sa and not grayed out..

Comment: @Aravinda You could always migrate your databases to the working instance.

Comment: that option sounds great.. I will try working on that..